# Columns with different numbers of rows

Tags: tables, multirow

I want to create a table with different numbers of rows on two columns, for example 5/4, 7/3, 2/3,... On each columns rows have to be equally divided in the vertical dimension. That means, for a 5/4, the height of the first column rows will be smaller than the height of the second column rows, but the total height of the first column will be equal to the total height of the second column.

Here a MWE with my different attempts:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

  % Using only multirow
  \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|l|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!70}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}\\
    \hline

    \multirow{4}{5cm}{
      \centering
      World company\newline
      Main Street\newline
      World Capital\newline
      Earth\newline
      Tel: +00~1~23~45~67~89
    }

     & Alphonse \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Daudet \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Marcel \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Pagnol \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{4\baselineskip}

  % Using makecell
  \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|l|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!70}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}\\
    \hline

    \makecell{
      \centering
      World company \newline
      Main Street \newline
      World Capital \newline
      Earth \newline
      Tel: +00~1~23~45~67~89
    }

     & Alphonse \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Daudet \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Marcel \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Pagnol \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{4\baselineskip}

  % Using multirow and minipage
  \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|l|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!70}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}\\
    \hline

    \multirow{4}{5cm}{
      \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
        \centering
        World company \\
        Main Street \\
        World Capital \\
        Earth \\
        Tel: +00~1~23~45~67~89
      \end{minipage}
    }

     & Alphonse \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Daudet \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Marcel \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Pagnol \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{4\baselineskip}

  % Using multirow on second column
  \begin{tabular}[c]{|c|l|}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{blue!70}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}\\
    \hline

    World company &

    \multirow{5}{3cm}{
      \noindent
      Alphonse \newline
      \hrule
      Daudet \newline
      \hrule
      Marcel \newline
      \hrule
      Pagnol \newline
    } \\
    Main Street & \\
    World Capital & \\
    Earth & \\
    Tel: +00~1~23~45~67~89 & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

---

The first try uses only a `multirow` on the first column.
 Problems:

- the text is not correctly centered
- the fifth line of the first column is below the table

Good:

- the text starts at the top of the column

---

The second attempt uses the `makecell` command.
 Problem:

- `\newline`s are not taken into account

---

The third test uses a `minipage` inside a `multirow` on the first column.
 Problems:

- the text does not start at the beginning of the column
- the two last lines are below the table

Good:

- the text is correctly centered

---

The Last try uses `multirow` on the second column.
 Problems:

- the first line of the second column seems to be indented
- the `\hline` does not work into `multirow`, and `hrule` does not fit all the width
- the spacing between lines and text are not good
- the text of the second column is below the table

Good

- the first column is properly centered
- the first column text fits correctly the table

---

As you can see, each 'solutions' have its own problems, and I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose to use the `\makegapedcells` command from `makecell` to increase
the cells heights. As the right column has 4 cells, the total height of this column is fine.

However, `makecell`  has problems with colouring tables, and  in the present case, `rowcolor` does not work, so I removed the first (empty) row, and replaced it with a `\midrule` (from `booktabs`) , which can take an optional thickness argument, and works well with `\arrayrulecolor{...}`.

But this made the vertical outer lines disappear on the corresponding height, since the first row had been removed. So I removed all outer lines and replaced them with an `\fbox`, using the appropriate parameters.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

 {\setcellgapes{1ex}\makegapedcells
 \setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}
 \fbox{\begin{tabular}[c]{c|l}
\arrayrulecolor{blue!70}\midrule[12pt]
\arrayrulecolor{black}
    \hline

    \multirowcell{4}{%
      World company\\
      Main Street\\
      World Capital\\
      Earth\\
      Tel: +00\,1\,23\,45\,67\,89
    }

     & Alphonse \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Baudet \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Marcel \\
    \cline{2-2}
     & Pagnol \
  \end{tabular}}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does the job for the rows, but not for the alignment. The text is not well center*ed*

Comment: You mean in the multirow?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: \o/ thanks again